# I am facing this problem while doing npx create-react-app can anyone help me?

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, npx

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: Obvious question: have you tried to do what it says? With which results? You probably had run `npm install create-react-app` locally before

Comment: Try following the instructions on the terminal

Answer (score 0):

After:

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm cache verify`

Try this :

1. `npx clear-npx-cache` to clear your npx cache.
2. `npx create-react-app your-app` or `npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm`